# IBAction won't give me entry to next page? Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

[LoginViewController class codes and error page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rqwL.png)

[As you can see, I have identified. =/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OufQg.png)

Everything works except when I click login button it won't let me go to the next page. but the console in Xcode stated that I succeeded in logging in.

Why does everything work accordingly to the console but the simulator won't show me the next page? I'm new to swift and objective-C, thanks for understanding. ^^

Comment: Is it possible that in your login button method, that your first if statement evaluates to true, but in that nested if statement, it evaluates to false? That would also keep the console from saying that it failed. It would just say nothing.

Comment: So you tell me, I should take that statement out and place it somewhere else then the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

This because you dismiss the view controller when you successfully logged in. You used

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

So Definitely this do not navigate to other page you should use like this :-

```
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("View controller name", sender: self)
```

Comment: I have already connected "HomeView" to "LoginView" page, and now I have used anther segue, from "LoginView" to ""HomeView" and identified it. But doesn't seem to work.  "Use of unresolved identifier "HomeTableView", is the error now.

I also used Self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) on my registration page, which in turn turns me back to login page again.

Comment: Error is clear now, you didn't set the segue identifier here. Name your segue identifier as "HomeTableView".By the way update your question. Please add project class and error screen shot or text

Comment: I have updated my screenshots, Somehow I get strange errors like "Unknown class ViewController in Interface Builder file." But it does nothing, I have had it from the start and doesn't affect me, I think.

Comment: Error shows in "TableViewControlle" not as "HomeViewController". So find tableviewController and correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because there is a class TableViewController that isn't correctly defined. Go to your storyboard then your TableViewController then identity inspector and make sure you entered your custom class name. Also check in the connections inspector that there are no views defined in this view controller that have the white "!" sign next to them because this means they're not properly connected to your class.

Comment: Clicked on TableViewController, the custom class is set to TableViewController and in the swift file to.

I checked the other ViewControllers, it seems everything are in the right order, atleast for me.

Comment: Did you try going to the connections inspector and make sure that there are no views defined in this view controller that have the white "!" sign next to them because this means they're not properly connected to your class.

Comment: Yes, I have Khaled. =)